# Mixing html code and css styling in php code

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I am going through some PHP code which I inherited. I can see the CSS styling and HTML has been merged into the same php file. Needless to say it looks like dog food for me, and I think it's very wrong, but maybe I am missing something here...

- Would there be any logical reason whatsoever why this could make sense?? I am thinking about loading times or whatever..

Comment: It would make sense if they're inexperienced coders.

Comment: External css documents get cached by browser so its always best to make those external resources. Sadly php mixed with html has been the default...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why inline CSS or JS bad?

**Example**:

```
<div style="width: 800px; margin: 1em auto; font: bold 1em/1.2 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">
    <div style="float: left; width: 400px; padding: 1em 2em; font-size: 0.9em">
        <span id="get-shit" onclick="callSomeFunction()">News</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**HTML file size**

> Your HTML code will weigh more, i.e. a web page riddled with similar code will have a kb size that is a lot larger than necessary.

**Lack of caching**

> HTML code will never be cached. Contrary to that, external dependencies, such as CSS and JavaScript files, will be cached by the visitor’s web browser after the first visit – this means that instead of loading a lot of superfluous HTML code for every page in your web site the visitor visits, it will quickly retrieve all style and interaction locally from the web browser cache.

**Poor accessibility**

> When it comes to inline JavaScript code, such as in the above example, it’s applied to an element which doesn’t have any built-in fallback interaction handler (i.e., like a link takes you to the URL specified in its href attribute etc). This means that it won’t work when JavaScript, for one reason or the other, isn’t available.

**Difficult code maintenance**

> When it comes to making changes to the code, I’m sure every web developer would agree on that having code in just one centralized location is a lot more preferable than changing exactly the same kind of code snippets spread all over the files in the web site. Maintaining similar code to the above for an entire web site would be hell.

Answer (score 0):

It were making sense if you generate parts of your css or html code. Anyways in this case I'd recommend to use template files which do only output the variables.

Having all code in one file, might reduce the number of includes, but increases the size of the one file which requires to be included.
I recommend to first focus on developing a running webapplication, and than fix the performance bottlenecks. There are tools like apc_cache for database query results or file_caches for rarley changing html output.

As you already realized, mixed php & html/css code with functionality is harder to read.

One fact which shows that my answer is correct is, that every modern framework uses template files. ZendFramework CakePHP or Codeigniter for example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't follow what it changes when template files are used. The code I am looking at is using CodeIgniter with templates.

Comment: If template files are used, they contain only the html/code and the output of the php code and maybe some structuring elements like <?php if($var):?> <?php endif;?>

The advantage is a separation of output-code and functionality-code which increases the maintainability.

Comment: These template files I am looking at, which are loaded from the main php file (with $this->template->load()....), contain everything html, css and js.